# Discussing one-one onto.

Tags: functions

f: R2 to R2. f(x,y)= (e^x cosy, e^x siny). f is:
1. not one-one on all of R2.
2. one-one on some neighbourhood of any point in R2.
3. an onto map.
4. such that neighbourhood of any point surjects onto R2.

For 1-1, f1=f2 should give (x1,y1)=(x2,y2). But I couldn't go far with this method. Instead if I see that sin, cos are periodic functions, so, this would be a many-one function. But since their period is 2pi, this function would be 1-1 in pi neighbourhood of any point. So, 1st and 2nd are true.

Regarding onto, e^x cosy=a, e^x siny =b, e^2x=a2+b2. Does it imply that the range is an exponent curve? So whole of R2 won't be covered? Even if we make an open ball around any point, all of it won't represent the range. So, 3rd and 4th are incorrect.

Seeking your confirmation regarding my explanation.

Comment: x is the log f the radius of the circle your point is on (with center 0) and y is the angle for your point.

Answer (score 1):

For 1-1, what is $f(0,0)$ and $f(0,2\pi)$?

For 1-1 in a neighbourhood around any point, yes, $(\cos(y),\sin(y))$ is 1-1 in a neighbourhood around any given $y$, since $cos(y)$ is 1-1 in a neighbourhood of every point that is not an integer multiple of $\pi$, but at those points, $\sin(y)$ is clearly 1-1 in a small enough neighbourhood, and $e^x$ is 1-1 for all $x$-values, so as long as your neighbourhood of $(x, y)$ doesn't span too much in the $y$-direction, you're good.

Regarding onto, can we ever have $f(x, y) = (0,0)$?